# File path is empty for google drive files

Tags: java, android, file-upload, remote-server

I am developing a file uploading android application. My objective is to upload the user selected file from file manager to a remote server. But when a google drive file is selected , file uploading fails because of empty path . Can somebody help me  ?

My code is :

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File to Upload.."), PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST) {
            if (data == null) {
                //no data present
                return;
            }
            Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(mActivity, selectedFileUri);
            if (selectedFilePath != null && !selectedFilePath.equals("")) {
                callUploadDocumentAPI();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, StringConstants.CANT_UPLOAD_TO_SERVER, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I have written my code in the question now

Comment: `callUploadDocumentAPI()` take no arguments? How does it take `selectedFilePath`?

Comment: @Kristopher I am handling it in that method actually , using that selectedFilePath string value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when a google drive file is selected , file uploading fails because of empty path .

`FilePath.getPath(mActivity, selectedFileUri)` cannot work. A `Uri` is not a file.

Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Either use that `InputStream` directly, or use it to make your own copy of the content in some file that you control, then use that copy.